# What dose this statement mean in python deap package?

Tags: python, import, deap

There are some statements in the **init**.py file of python DEAP package, such as:

```
from .crossover import *
```

Is this means import all function from crossover.py? So why there is a "." in front of crossover. It would be so much appreciated that if somebody could help me understand the meaning of `.` and `*` in the statement.

Comment: the `.` means your current directory is probably a python package (contains a `__init__.py` file) and that `crossover.py` is probably in the same directory as the file you're in. The `*` means import everything in that file.

Comment: Thanks. It actually duplicates with the one you referred.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python imports names from files and gives you access to them in the interpreter or other files. This is all a part of the [Module](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/modules.html) system used in Python.

The star (asterisk) means "add all of the names from that file to my current working list of names."

The '.' in front of crossover is a [relative import](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/). This means, relative to your current location (in an interpreter or a file) find a file called "crossover"

All together:

Import all of the names of in a module called crossover that is located within the current directory.